# Can an object contain another object of the same type?

Tags: php

I read several questions and answers for other languages, but did not see any specifically for PHP.

Would the following be valid in PHP?

```
class foo 
{
    // constructor, etc..

    public function bar()
    {
        $newFoo = new foo();
        // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: `Would the following be valid in PHP?` Well, have you tried it?

Comment: StackOverflow is not your compiler. Just try it and see if it works.

Comment: Agreeing on him trying, but the question would be, even if it is working, is it the right thing to do? I guess a fair question from someone new?

Comment: @TimCooper - I suppose I phrased my question poorly. In my limited experience, things often work when they shouldn't. I have done funky things many times in PHP and Javascript that I later learned I should not have. In addition to asking if what I did is syntactically correct, I also wanted to see if it is considered an acceptable practice. Thanks for the down vote.

Comment: @TimCooper - Oh, and I did try it, by the way: it worked fine. Notice I did not ask if it would "work," I asked if it is "valid."

Comment: @Nate, this is commonly done in Singleton pattern, but from a static member function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it would be valid. You can create nested sets of objects. (Though doing it in the constructor would cause an infinite recursion!)

**Extra!** You can even link an object to itself!

```
$this->myself = $this;
```

And it would link to the same object.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's valid, as long as you don't create an object of the same type in the constructor.

Comment: That.. didn't make sense. Could you rephrase that?

Comment: 'Time' was changed to 'type'.. a typo, still does not make sense?

Comment: If you create the same class in teh constructor, it will lead to a recursive loop...

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing that prevents it.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Yes it works!

You can instantiate your Objects in almost any place of your php code. Inside a class method is not different, but you must make sure to include your class file first if it's a different class, something like

```
<?php

    require_once './foo.class.php';

    class bar{
        //class stuff
        public doThingsWithFoo(){
            $foo = new foo();
        }
    }
?>
```

In your particular case you seems to be searching for the [$this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php) keyword. From the manual:

> The pseudo-variable $this is available when a method is called from within an object context. $this is a reference to the calling object (usually the object to which the method belongs, but possibly another object, if the method is called statically from the context of a secondary object).

In your example then:

```
class foo 
{
    // constructor, etc..

    public function bar()
    {
        $this->useAMethodFromThisClass();
        // do something
    }
}
```

But there's nothing (except maybe common sense) in using another instance of the same object in a method of the same class, much like you are doing:

```
class foo 
{
    // constructor, etc..

    public function bar()
    {
        $newFoo = new foo();
        // do something with this instance of foo that you cannot do using $this
    }
}
```

I hope it helped. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

best way to know if something is valid in PHP is to use this function in your header file:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL|E_NOTICE);
?>
```

Even PHP will report failures, such as not using "isset ()".

---

Other practices:

- Always use `$_GET`, `$_POST` instead of `global`
- Do not use this: `$_GET["test"]` this is the best `$_GET['test']`
- Always read the PHP documentation to see if the function is
  deprecated (doc: http://www.php.net/manual)

`Note:` your "constructor" is "valid".

Comment: Sorry, it was the fault of the spell checker
now fix (I edited my answer)